# Laravel package's composer require

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have created a package for Laravel, the package is using its own composer.json for specifying requirements. The problem is how to make Laravel's composer to "include" the package's composer requirements? so that when I run composer update the package requirements installed along with the app requirements.

I used normal composer for package:

Path: app/packages/intropkg/composer.json

`"require": {
        "spatie/emoji": "^1.0"
    },`

but when calling the package from Laravel I get the error: Class 'Spatie\Emoji\Emoji' not found

Laravel composer related config:

Path: app/composer.json

`"autoload": {
...
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Lsdev\\Intropkg\\": "packages/intropkg/src"
        }
}`

- [Package code](https://github.com/wesamly/intropkg)

Comment: Have you done `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: did you run any composer command to get the dependencies?

Comment: where did you add the require for that `emoji` package?

Comment: If you modified your composer.json directly (ie you did not run `composer require spatie/emoji`) then you need to run `composer install` to install the new package.

Comment: I have already tried all that guys :( I'll add paths of composer files, I feel confusion here. please read the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you called `composer update` (not `install`!) after editing `composer.json`? Just running `install` will not pick up new dependencies

Comment: Yes I did @nico

Comment: And does the `vendor` directory contain a folder for `spatie/emoji`?

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: Could you run `composer update` again, just to see if anything changes? If `spatie/emoji` is currently not installed, but listed in the root `composer.json`, it should get installed...